# Does selecting a set of random numbers for the key and IV insure security?

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis, key-exchange, initialization-vector

For AES 256 - if I use a random 32 byte sequence for the 256 bit key and another 16 byte for the 128 bit initialization vector, does this insure that my cipher text cannot be broken in any short amount of time when the byte sequences are only known to me?

Related to this: how would one transmit the key to another party, so he/she may decrypt the cipher text keep it secret? Is there a preferred method, for instance by word of mouth only?

Answer (score 1):

So your question has some holes in them but I will try to fill as much in as possible. If anyone were to see a mistake in my explanation, I would be more than happy if they pointed it out or edited this solution.

1. AES is a block cipher that has many modes namely: ECB, CBC, OFB etc. each of these have slightly different properties (both cryptographic and non cryptographic) and benefits. That being said, AES-256 is secure (apart from ECB, and I will not dive into different different definitions of security. If interested look into CPA Secure and CCA secure). The matter now becomes which mode to use, for which there is a better explanation explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220751/how-to-choose-an-aes-encryption-mode-cbc-ecb-ctr-ocb-cfb)

Hopefully that answers your question. Let me know if there is something I missed.

2. As for your second question you would want to use a public key exchange protocol. I would suggest using [Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange)

Answer (score 0):

> For AES 256 - if I use a random 32 byte sequence for the 256 bit key and another 16 byte for the 128 bit initialization vector, does this insure that my cipher text cannot be broken in any short amount of time when the byte sequences are only known to me?

No. A random AES key and a random IV can seen as *good pre-requisites* to build a secure system. But AES-CBC mode of operation is for instance susceptible to padding oracle attacks, and AES-GCM is limited to the amount of input plaintext. So even with a perfect AES key and random IV your system may be vulnerable, even on the level of the algorithms used.

You could also say: Yes, but only if they are applied correctly in an otherwise secure system.

> Related to this: how would one transmit the key to another party, so he/she may decrypt the cipher text keep it secret? Is there a preferred method, for instance by word of mouth only?

No, it depends on the protocol on how keys are *established* between two parties.

Word of mouth is generally not thought of to be all that practical. Most persons won't be able to remember 64 hexadecimal characters from the top of their head: keys are simply too complex for that. There are however ways of deriving a key from a password (using a Password Based Key Derivation Function or PBKDF).

You can pre share a key using public key cryptography (e.g. PGP), perform Diffie-Hellman key agreement, simply send a USB stick with a key on it, derive the key from a master key etc. etc. etc. Books are written about key management.